# Add to cart only works after item second item and then both items show

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, addtocart, model

I am trying to add a product to the cart through a controller, one the first attempt the basket is loaded, and says there is nothing in it. Once I reload the controller for a second time the item is added and the basket it shown - with both the first and second item. The code being run each time is exactly the same.

```
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $eventProduct */
        $eventProduct = $this->productsHelper->getProductById($eventProductId);

        // Set relevant options
        $params = [
            'product' => $eventProductId,
            'related_product' => null,
            'options' => [
                25 => $referenceNumber,
                26 => "{$event->getTitle()} on {$event->getEventDate()}"
            ],
            'qty' => $qty
        ];

        // Add to cart
        $cart = $this->cartHelper->getCart();
        $cart->addProduct($eventProduct, $params);
        $cart->save();

        return $this->_redirect("checkout/cart/index");
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trouble shooting I found that the code above is correct, however it was failing to appear like I was adding anything to the cart because above this script a user was being logged in. The result in the cache being mismatched I can only assume.

I resolved this by separating the add to cart code in to a new controller where the would then have been loaded as the logged in user.